# Salesforce Sites - Authorization required for Visualforce page with Site URL but not --c.visualforce.com/apex

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I've set up [Salesforce Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.meta/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide/sites_setup_overview.htm) on a scratch org and created a public Visualforce page `AccountEdit`.

If I go to

1. http://*mydomain*.cs97.force.com/AccountEdit

I see the message "Authorization Required", but I can reach the page via

2. http://*mydomain*--c.visualforce.com/apex/AccountEdit

Is there a way to see this Visualforce page with the friendlier URL format **1**?

(NOTE: If I remove the custom controller from my AccountEdit page, then I can view the page without the "Authorization Required" message using URL format **1**.)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by creating an Apex class that implement implements the interface Site.UrlRewriter.

You can find details at the following link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm